# hadoop streaming failed with error code 1 in RHadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

I am working with RHadoop by the following code:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.0.0.jar")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64")

library(rJava)
library(rhdfs)
library(rmr2)
hdfs.init()

mapper = function (., X) {
  n=nrow(X);
  ones=matrix(rep(1,n),nrow=n,ncol=1);
  ag=aggregate(cbind(ones,X[,1:79]),by=list(X[,80]),FUN="sum")
  key=factor(ag[,1]);
  keyval(key,split(ag[,-1],key))
}

reducer = function(k, A) {
  keyval(k,list(Reduce('+', A)))
}

GroupSums <-  from.dfs( mapreduce(input = "/ISCXFlowMeter.csv", map = mapper, reduce = reducer, combine = T))
```

When I run this code, I get an error as:

> packageJobJar: [/tmp/hadoop-unjar7138506441946536619/] []
>   /tmp/streamjob6099552934186757596.jar tmpDir=null 2018-06-12
>   22:40:04,651 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at
>   /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-06-12 22:40:04,945 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting
>   to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-06-12 22:40:05,201 INFO
>   mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path:
>   /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/uel/.staging/job_1528838017005_0012
>   2018-06-12 22:40:06,158 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files
>   to process : 1 2018-06-12 22:40:06,171 INFO net.NetworkTopology:
>   Adding a new node: /default-rack/127.0.0.1:9866 2018-06-12
>   22:40:06,233 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
>   2018-06-12 22:40:06,348 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-06-12
>   22:40:06,608 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:
>   job_1528838017005_0012 2018-06-12 22:40:06,610 INFO
>   mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: [] 2018-06-12
>   22:40:06,945 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
>   2018-06-12 22:40:06,945 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find
>   'resource-types.xml'. 2018-06-12 22:40:07,022 INFO
>   impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application
>   application_1528838017005_0012 2018-06-12 22:40:07,249 INFO
>   mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:
>   http://uel-Deskop-VM:8088/proxy/application_1528838017005_0012/
>   2018-06-12 22:40:07,251 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:
>   job_1528838017005_0012 2018-06-12 22:40:09,301 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job
>   job_1528838017005_0012 running in uber mode : false 2018-06-12
>   22:40:09,305 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 2018-06-12
>   22:40:09,337 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1528838017005_0012 failed
>   with state FAILED due to: Application application_1528838017005_0012
>   failed 2 times due to AM Container for
>   appattempt_1528838017005_0012_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
>   Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-06-12 22:40:08.734]Exception
>   from container-launch. Container id:
>   container_1528838017005_0012_02_000001 Exit code: 127
>
> [2018-06-12 22:40:08.736]Container exited with a non-zero exit code
>   127. Error file: prelaunch.err. Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err : Last 4096 bytes of stderr : /bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or
>   directory
>
> [2018-06-12 22:40:08.736]Container exited with a non-zero exit code
>   127. Error file: prelaunch.err. Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err : Last 4096 bytes of stderr : /bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or
>   directory
>
> For more detailed output, check the application tracking page:
>   http://uel-Deskop-VM:8088/cluster/app/application_1528838017005_0012
>   Then click on links to logs of each attempt. . Failing the
>   application. 2018-06-12 22:40:09,368 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
>   2018-06-12 22:40:09,369 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
>   Streaming Command Failed! Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce,
>   combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  :    hadoop streaming failed
>   with error code 1
>   >

ISCXFlowMeter.csv file in hadoop is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbppzg6x2slzcjz/ISCXFlowMeter.csv?dl=1

Could you please guide me how to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a while, by adding the following properties into `mapred-site.xml`, I could rectify the error.

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
</property>
```

But, the issue now is that, the key-value is NULL after completing map-reduce. Any help, I appreciate it.